# Center align image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align this image in the center of the page. I've tried " (in the body)" "text-align:center; and display:inline-block; (in the css)" but they don't work.

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4TtHR/1/

Here's the CSS:

```
figure {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible dublicate of [How to center a div in a div - horizontally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-a-div-in-a-div-horizontally?rq=1) among many others

Comment: @megawac I just tried several things from that link and none of it worked. I set the margins as well as a few other things which had no result.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4TtHR/9/

Comment: @megawac Nope doesn't work. Check your work sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to center a floated element.

You can simply wrap it in a `div`, set it to `display:inline-block` in order to contain the child element. Then apply `text-align:center` to the `parent` in order to center the `div`.

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/8tKFB/)

Answer (score 1):

```
figure {
display: block;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 50%;
}
```